# How to align terms in alignat: too much spaces and too few

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, mathtools, alignat

Please, help me
this code has too much spaces and too few, how can I fix it?

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\forall i \in[m]  &&  \sum \limits_{e \in N_{out(s_{i})}} y(i,e) - \sum \limits_{e \in N_{in(s_{i})}} y(i,e) =1\\
\forall i \in[m], v \in V \{s_{i}, v_{i}\}  && \sum \limits_{e \in N_{out(v)}} y(i,e) - \sum \limits_{e \in N_{in(v)}} y(i,e) =0\\
\forall i \in[m]  && \sum \limits_{e \in E} y(i,e) \leq w\\
\forall i \in[m], v \in V && \sum \limits_{e'=u',v'} y(i,e') \min \left\{1, \frac{d(u',v')^ \alpha}{d(u',v)^ \alpha}\right\} \leq w\\
\forall i \in[m], e \in E  &&   y(i,e) \in \{0,1\}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

this is what I have: 
[image]

this is what I need:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not understood that to have two alignment  groups, you need three `&`. I replaced `amsmath` with `mathtools` (which loads the former), in order to use the `\mathclap` command, to have better horizontal spacing around the (aligned) Σ's.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\geometry{a4paper}

\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 & \forall i \in[m] && \sum_{\mathclap{e \in N_{\mathrm{out}(s_{i})}}} y(i,e) - \sum_{\mathclap{e \in N_{\mathrm{in}(s_{i})}}} y(i,e) =1\\
 & \forall i \in[m], v \in V \{s_{i}, v_{i}\} & \hspace{3em} & \sum_{\mathclap{e \in N_{\mathrm{out}(v)}}} y(i,e) - \sum_{\mathclap{e \in N_{\mathrm{in}(v)}}} y(i,e) =0\\
 & \forall i \in[m] && \sum_{e \in E} y(i,e) \leq w\\
 & \forall i \in[m], v \in V && \sum_{\mathclap{e'=u',v'}} y(i,e') \min \left\{1, \frac{d(u',v')^ \alpha}{d(u',v)^ \alpha}\right\} \leq w\\
 & \forall i \in[m], e \in E && y(i,e) \in \{0,1\}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]